# Find an injective map

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$Q )$ If $A \subset B$, find an injective map $m:X^{A}\to X^B$

My solution:

$$ f\in X^A \implies f:A \to X$$

and we can define $m(f)\in X^B $ as
$$m(f): B \to X$$
$$ m(f)(b) =
\begin{cases}
f(b),  & \text{if $b \in A$ } \\
x, & \text{if $b \notin A$ }
\end{cases} \text{ where $x$ is some constant element of $X$}$$

To prove m is injective
$$\text m(f_1)=m(f_2)$$
$$\implies m(f_1)(b)=m(f_2)(b) \ \forall \ b\in \ B$$
$$\implies f_1(a)=f_2(a) \ \forall \ a\in A \ \text{ since} \ A \subset B $$
$$\implies f_1=f_2$$

Solution in the manual:

$m\left(\left(a_{11}, a_{12}, \ldots\right), \ldots,\left(a_{n 1}, a_{n 2}, \ldots\right)\right)=\left(a_{11}, a_{21}, \ldots, a_{n 1}, a_{12}, a_{22}, \ldots, a_{n 2}, \ldots\right)$. It maps to $B^\omega$ as $a_{i j} \in A \subset B$, and is clearly injective. It may be not be surjective (unlike (e)) if $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Both the solutions seem completely different. Can someone please tell me which is correct and if the answer in the solution manual is correct please explain it to me. How is $\left(\left(a_{11}, a_{12}, \ldots\right), \ldots,\left(a_{n 1}, a_{n 2}, \ldots\right)\right) \in X^A$ ?

Comment: Are you looking at the right question in the solution manual? That explicitly says the "answer" is in $B^{\omega}$, suggesting a question about mapping to $B^{\omega}$, not to $X^B$. I suspect you are looking in the wrong place, or at the wrong edition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have looked at two different solution manuals and they both have similar solutions. That's why I doubted my solution. Can you check mine and see if it is correct

Comment: For $A\subseteq B$ and some set $X$, $X^A$ doesn't inject into $X^B$ if and only if $X=A=\varnothing\ne B$, so this should be addressed. Your work is ok for $X\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio It is given in the question that X≠∅ even though I haven't mentioned it. Can you explain the reason behind the first line "For A⊆B and some set X, XA doesn't inject into XB if and only if X=A=∅≠B,"

Comment: What are $A, B,X$? Sets, groups, topological spaces, ... ?

Comment: @PaulFrost Just sets. X is non empty

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash I was sure that you deal with sets ;-). But you didn't explicitly mention that and I think the reader should get all necessary information at first glance, without enquiries. For future questions I recommend that you list all prerequisites and if necessary edit your question to include missing material.

Comment: And your proof is fine. Trust yourself!

Comment: @SiddharthPrakash If you look at what the set of functions $Y\to X$ is, you'll see that $\varnothing^\varnothing=\{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing^Y=\varnothing$ for all $Y\ne\varnothing$. This completes the discussion.